# Execution failed 'android-24' requires JDK 1.8 or later to compile

Tags: android, java-8, android-7.0-nougat

My build keeps failing and I am not able to run a hello world app in the console or with the AVD.

Also, I'm not sure how you would setup the JUnit testing with Android Studio

I have JDK 1.8 installed

[image: I have JDK 1.8 installed]

But, This is what happens in Android Studio

[image: This is what happens in Android Studio]

Comment: your log says you have the JRE 8 installed. You need the JDK if you want to compile anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S` for Windows/Linux to pull up the **"Project Structure"** dialog. In there, you can set the JDK location as well as the Android SDK location.

[image]

To get your JDK location, run `/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` in terminal

Comment: I will try this and let you know if it works. I know for a fact I downloaded JDK 8 or better because I was running a test app before today just fine.

Comment: That Java 8 version is quite out of date :)

Answer (score 1):

Error says clearly: you don't have Oracle JDK 8 installed on your PC.

Go to: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Download and install on your computer

Then open Android Studio, go to `File->Project Structure...` and using `...` find your JDK 8 already installed.

Go to `File -> Invalidate caches/Restaert` and choose `Invalidate and Restart`.

Now it should work properly

Answer (score 0):

You need JDK 1.8 or later, which means that you need the Java 8 JDK - because you're compiling with Android 7.0 (SDK 24). You can download it for free from the Oracle site. Also, if you're on Linux, my recommended method of installation is via WebUpd8 PPA on Debian-based Linux distros (it takes care of setting it up for you).

Comment: I had JDK 8 installed on my computer what the log says is wrong because before today I was able to run a test app with no issues

Comment: Try setting up the project (piotrek's answer)